# How to combine two column results in one column with a separator

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query like

```
select a.host_coll_code AS "Code", a.description AS "DESCRIPTION" 
from coll_collateral a
```

When this query runs I get result something like this

```
   Code          DESCRIPTION
  ---------------------------
   123              ABC
   589              UYR
   ...              ...
```

I want to get the result in one column with a separator like

```
Code and Description
---------------------
      123-ABC
      589-UYR
      ....
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `concat` function or concatenation operator `||`:

```
SQL> with t1(Code, DESCRIPTION) as(
  2    select 123, 'ABC' from dual union all
  3    select 589, 'UYR' from dual
  4  )
  5  select concat(concat(to_char(code), '-'), DESCRIPTION) result
  6    from t1
  7  ;

RESULT
-----------
123-ABC
589-UYR
```

OR

```
select to_char(code) || '-' || Description result
  from t1

 RESULT
-----------
123-ABC
589-UYR
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.host_coll_code || '-' || a.description AS "Code and Description" 
from coll_collateral a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select CAST(a.host_coll_code AS VARCHAR(100))
       ||'-'||
       a.description AS "CODE_AND_DESCRIPTION" 
from coll_collateral a
```